# How to get float value inside String in Android?

Tags: android, string, range

Currently i am working in simple android application, i have one string like Result below i mentioned for your reference, then i tried to get the rate value like 0.036, but i can't it, how to get this? Is it possible? please help me

Thanks in Advance

```
String Result =@" NO_Balance | MobileNumber: 43994732984 | rate: 0.036";
```

Comment: post your code, whatever you have tried

Comment: if (result.contains("rate:")) 
{

}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

String someString =" NO_Balance | MobileNumber: 43994732984 | rate: 0.036";

```
// last float value
Float f = Float.valueOf(
            someString.substring(
                 someString.lastIndexOf('.'), 
                 someString.length()));

// center int value
int num = Integer.valueOf(
            someString.substring(
                 someString.indexOf(':')+1,
                 someString.lastIndexOf('|')-1));
```

note this assumes the string your parsing is valid, you may want to do some checking

Comment: How to get the mobile number? can u please help this

Answer (score 0):

If you just want the rate, do it that way:

```
String[] parts = Result.split(" | ");
String[] keyval = parts[2].split(": ");
float rate = parseFloat(keyval[1]);
```

You can also get the "MobileNumber" like this:

```
keyval = parts[1].split(": ");
String mobileNumber = keyval[1];
```

NOTE: BOTH examples assume, that the string is similar each time, except for the numbers! If the order or number of fields seperated by " | " may change, you need a more sophisticated solution:

```
HashMap<String, String> values = new HashMap<String, String>();
String[] parts = CurrentString.split(" | ");

foreach( String part : parts) {
  String[] keyval = parts[2].split(": ");

  if (keyval.length == 2) {
    values.put(keyval[0], keyval[1]);
  } else {
    values.put(keyval[0], "exists");
  }
}

float rate = parseFloat(values.get("rate"));
```

Comment: Now i tried this, then i update you

Comment: I tried this, String[] parts = Result.split(" | ");
                     String[] keyval = parts[1].split(": ");
                     String mobileNumber = keyval[1];
                     System.out.println("mobileNumber : "+mobileNumber); Error comes in threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d800)

Comment: Is your original String really " NO_Balance | MobileNumber: 43994732984 | rate: 0.036" and NOT "NO_Balance|MobileNumber:43994732984|rate:0.036" ???

Comment: Ok, maybe split only accepts a single character as delimiter (e.g. "|" and not " | "). Have no possibility to try the code here. Same is for ": " ... you need to split by ":"; later you can remove whitespaces at beginning and end using trim();

Answer (score 0):

The following uses a Java `Regex` to determine a `float` in your `String`

```
    public class RegEx {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String Result = " NO_Balance | MobileNumber: 43994732984 | rate: 0.036";
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\d+\\.\\d+");
        Matcher m = p.matcher(Result);
        if (m.find()) {
            System.out.println(m.group(0));
        } else
            System.out.println("No float found:(");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do this would be to do the following:

```
    String result = " NO_Balance | MobileNumber: 43994732984 | rate: 0.036";

    int index = result.indexOf("rate: ");

    String test = result.substring(index + 6);

    Float theValue = Float.valueOf(test);

    Log.d("testing", test);

    Log.d("testing2", String.valueOf(theValue));
```